# No puedo crear ni modificar columna de tipo JSON en MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

Estoy intentando agregar una columna para almacenar objetos JSON en mi base de datos MySQL.

Mi configuración es la siguiente:

> ```
> Versión de MySQL:    5.6.32-78.1.
> Engine de la tabla:  MyIsam.
> Base de datos alojada en un hosting compartido (Bluehost)
> ```

Lo he intentado así:

```
ALTER TABLE `liturgia_horas_completas_salmos` 
ADD COLUMN `json_data` JSON AFTER  `salmos`;
```

Y me lanza el error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'JSON AFTER  `salmos`' at line 2

También he creado una columna del tipo `TEXT`:

```
ALTER TABLE `liturgia_horas_completas_salmos` 
ADD COLUMN `json_data` TEXT AFTER  `salmos`;
```

La misma se crea bien, luego introduzco un json válido en ella y trato de cambiarla a JSON así:

```
ALTER TABLE `liturgia_horas_completas_salmos` MODIFY `json_data` JSON;
```

Y también me da error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'JSON' at line 1

¿Qué podría hacer para tener una columna con tipo de dato JSON?

Comment: que versión de MySQL estas usando?

Comment: Actualmente estoy en la versión `5.6.32-78.1`. La BD reside en un hosting compartido de Bluehost, @AlfredoPaz

Comment: los datos de tipo JSON solo son soportados en MySQL 5.7 y MySQL 8

Comment: @AlfredoPaz ¿alguna referencia? [No lo veo aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html), haciendo una lectura rápida.

Comment: lo vi en un blog hace poco siento no tener el enlace justo ahora pero JSON como tipo de dato solo se soporta en esas versiones

Comment: El soporte a JSON se incorporó a partir de la versión 5.7.8: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-8.html#mysqld-5-7-8-json y https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Comment: si exacto lo que le comentaba @Gerry gracias por otro lado A. Cedano que la sintáxis que manejas es correcta pero en tanto uses una versión de las que te indico

Comment: Entiendo. Entonces no me queda otra que guardarlo en un `TEXT` por ahora, hasta que Bluehost decida actualizar la versión de MySQL. Gracias por los enlaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El tipo de dato JSON en el gestor de bases de datos MySQL, se incluyó a partir de la versión 5.7 y en MariaDB desde la versión 10.2.7, anexo también el enlace

Referencia: [JSON DATA TYPE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-8.html#mysqld-5-7-8-json)

Referencia para MariDB: [JSON DATA TYPE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json-data-type/)

Anexo a lo anterior te dejo un ejemplo de la sintáxis a manejar

**CREAMOS LA BASE DE DATOS DONDE TRABAJAREMOS**

```
CREATE DATABASE ols;
```

**HACEMOS USO DE LA BASE DE DATOS RECIÉN CREADA**

```
USE ols;
```

**CREAMOS UNA TABLA**

```
CREATE TABLE demo(
 name VARCHAR(100),
 edad INT NOT NULL
)ENGINE=myISAM;
```

**HACEMOS UN ALTER PARA AGREGAR UNA COLUMNA TIPO JSON**

```
alter table demo 
add column propiedades JSON not null
after edad;
```